# How to add fixture image to element in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a react application that requires the URL of an image as text input, then after submitting the URL, the image from the URL gets displayed in an `<img>` by setting it's src attribute.

I'm writing a test in Cypress and I want to either stub this request to return the fixture image or just display my fixture image on the page by attaching it to an element.
What I tried:

- Used route2 to stub this image request and return my fixture image as a response, but it put the cypress runner in an infinite loop by calling the url of the image endessly:
  [image]
  The documentation of route2 say it's able to intercept resource loads, so should it be possible somehow with this?

  ```
  cy.route2('GET', '**/kids.jpg', {
         statusCode: 200,
         fixture: `${FIXTURES_APP_PATH}kids.jpg`
      })
  ```
- Used the 'cypress-file-upload' package to attach the fixture image file as a blob to the img element (had to replace special chars because the `base64StringToBlob` threw an 'Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded' error).

  ```
  cy.fixture(`${FIXTURES_APP_PATH}kids.jpg`, 'base64')
  .then(fixture =>
  {
      Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(fixture.replace(/^[^,]+,/, ''), 'image/jpg')
  })
  .then((fileContent: Blob) =>
  {
      cy.get(AppPage.INPUT_IMG)
        .attachFile({filePath: `${FIXTURES_APP_PATH}kids.jpg`, fileContent, mimeType: 'image/jpg'});
  });
  ```

What am I doing wrong? How could this be done?
Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug with stubbing image responses via fixtures that will be fixed in Cypress 5.5.0. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/8916

Comment: Thank you! I guess it should be released in a few days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for the stubbing issue was released in https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v5.5.0